# AWS Amplify App - URL path returns access denied

Tags: aws-amplify

I have an app that I am using AWS Amplify to build and deploy. If I go to

https://master.XXXXXXX.amplifyapp.com

then the landing page for the app works fine. However, if I go to ...

https://master.XXXXXXX.amplifyapp.com/page

then I get the error below ...

[image]

Why is this happening?
How do I fix this?

Comment: This is usually caused by SPA routing. Here's the documentation for this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html

Answer (score 0):

[How to fix Access Denied error on AWS Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72942099/how-to-fix-access-denied-error-on-aws-amplify)

Please see this. One of the reasons can be missing index.html file.

Amplify excepts the index.html file as the default file to load. If this file is missing, we will get that error. Name your default page as index.html and it should load.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).