# How to fix Access Denied error on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, aws-amplify

I am trying to host my web app on AWS Amplify, I compressed my HTML, CSS, and Javascript files on a zip file, and I select the drag and drop option and click deploy, but every time after deploying the app and opening the temporary Domain I get the following message:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>7JBBK8RRTJF3VHV</RequestId>
<HostId>18ByyhCUEGmmK3Ka9XUzt967ZAvCixtHT0NgL2Nzqby3fxue9e8eauIljm0gulU754gMcV2LoO8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any help?

Comment: There is not a lot to go by from the information provided in the post. I would recommend checking if there is additional information in Cloudwatch logs or in Cloudtrail which gives a more descriptive error. However, the AccessDenied error does indicate that there are insufficient permissions for the operation you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it was a mistake on my part when naming the document, I name the document examplev1-dashboard.html, however when deploying the website AWS couldn't access it, I change the name to index.html and it did deploy correctly.